# How to return a value with COALESCE when a SELECT statement returns nothing?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello Stackoverflow community !

I got this code :

```
(SELECT COALESCE(id, 0) FROM members WHERE user_id = 1225282512438558720)
UNION ALL
(SELECT COALESCE(id, 0) FROM channels WHERE channel_id = 720694686028791971)
UNION ALL
(SELECT COALESCE(id, 0) FROM guilds WHERE guild_id = 831900150115991605);
```

Each statement could or not could return a value (because nothing corresponds to the WHERE Clause)

My problem is that if for example the first statement returns nothing then Postgres is going to return me this

```
 coalesce
----------
        6
        1
```

but i want that Postgres returns me this :

```
 coalesce
----------
     NULL
        6
        1
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: It should do be 0  6  1 coalesce will never return  null

Comment: Are you expecting only one result from each subquery or could there be more than one row?

Comment: Each tables which are called by each select statement can only receive one row (one int value), each table has a UNIQUE constraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query returns nothing because no rows satisfy filter criteria. To return rows from the empty result set you need to do aggregation. So you need:

```
(SELECT max(id) FROM members WHERE user_id = 1225282512438558720)
UNION ALL
(SELECT max(id) FROM channels WHERE channel_id = 720694686028791971)
UNION ALL
(SELECT max(id) FROM guilds WHERE guild_id = 831900150115991605);
```

Comment: OP wants `null` as output:)

Answer (score 2):

For multiple columns or results, you can left-join an unary row table to each of your inputs

```sql
WITH dual AS (select 1)
(SELECT COALESCE(id, 0) FROM dual LEFT JOIN members ON user_id = 1225282512438558720)
UNION ALL
(SELECT COALESCE(id, 0) FROM dual LEFT JOIN channels ON channel_id = 720694686028791971)
UNION ALL
(SELECT COALESCE(id, 0) FROM dual LEFT JOIN guilds ON guild_id = 831900150115991605);
```